# aligning 3 div columns at top with various content affecting its condition

Tags: html, css

I've searched google and SO for a solution to this problem but have not found it, perhaps this is due to my uncertainty as to how to word it best.

Here is the issue:

I have a 3 column page using divs. The divs are as follow, left, middle and right container divs, with various content inside. What I need them to do is align horizontally from the top. What they are currently doing is some jigsaw jagged aligning. I believe this is because of the content inside (as I've altered everything else without result), which varies from titles with padding around it, to text, fb like buttons, etc. As you can see here, http://sunnahspace.com the temporary double line on the page is what I am trying to align them against. I can post all the code you need but as it is a lot I would prefer not to bog everyone down with a lot of reading, I will post the css and if you ask for something specific I will post it, otherwise it can be viewed from the source for the index page linked above. And please go easy on me, I'm a bit of an idiot when it comes to developing, and I'm sure you've all been noobs before. Thanks in advance.

Here is the css for the 3 divs:

```css
#middle_container {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:auto;
}

#right_container {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}

#left_container {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why is your markup so jigjag?

Comment: I mean, The containers arranged side by side are not under same parent. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: the way I've written it (though though my edits they may of been messed up, im sifting the code again to make sure, if you can point something out itd be greatly appreciated), is that there is a body container, inside of which will be the bar for adding to fb, google, etc. below which should be the 3 columns with other divs inside separating content. I'm not sure how they are under different parents, perhaps that is the issue, I'm going through it now to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, check that, Organising the layout, can be as easy as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/CNmBC/)

Comment: Oh this is awesome, thanks for the share! I'm sorting it all now, I'll respond as soon as it is cleaned up. I've deleted the unnecessary Lorem Ipsum to make it easier on the eyes.

Comment: ok, I've cleared up the code and as best as I can tell a few closing divs were missing but I've replaced them but I am still having the same issue. Can you point out as to how the divs are under different parents?

Comment: There are million ways they can get there, but I think you solved your problem right?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tool above, Whitney Sarah Rogers caught the problem quick so thanks to both of you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIrst of all you need to take off the first spacer above the first column_middle_temp1.

Second you need to remove margin-bottom: 20px from the top_container.

Lastly you need to add a  at the bottom of:

```
<div id="left_container">...</div><br clear="all" />
```

This is what I saw right away, if this still doesn't work let me know.

Comment: after removing the extra spacer it aligned perfectly, good catch and thank you! I guess the lesson to learn for anyone else who stumbles across this problem is to clean up the code. Thank you again.